# cakePHP, multiple hasOne in a single model

Tags: php, cakephp

say you have 3 models : user, hair_color, and eye_color

user hasOne hair_color
user also hasOne eye_color

however

```
var $hasOne = 'hair_color';
var $hasOne = 'eye_color';
```

obviously wont work. So how do you implement many hasOne relationships in a single model?

I assume the answer is in the cookbook, Im going over that area now, I suspect it has something to do with passing an array to $hasOne, but no example of doing this.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
var $hasOne = array('HairColor', 'EyeColor'); 
// hasOne is an array of model names **not file names**
```

OR

```
var $hasOne = array(
    'HairColor' => array(
        'className'    => 'HairColor',
         ...
    ),
    'EyeColor' => array(
        'className'    => 'EyeColor',
         ...
    )
);
```

You should read manual http://book.cakephp.org/view/80/hasOne

Comment: was looking at pg 78 lol, tyvm edit : just realized I was on the right page just the long version of it. Also, I dont see your 1st method spelled out there, I guess it could be inferred... Still, tyvm. :-)